# Subtitle output at the wrong location

Tags: html, wordpress

I can't understand why did my subtitle appears at the top of the contents when I've set it at below the titles

```
$output .= '<article class="' . esc_attr( $columns ) . '" data-categories="' . trim( $data_categories ) . '" >';    
if( $post_thumbnail_img ) { 
    $output .= '<a href="' . $permalink . '" title="' . get_the_title() . '"' . $lightbox_class . '>';
    $output .= '<img src="' . $post_thumbnail_img[0] . '" alt="' . $post_thumbnail_data['alt'] . '" class="entry-image ' . $post_thumbnail_data['class'] . '">';        
    $output .= '</a>';  
}

$output .= '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '" class="project-meta">';
$output .= '<h5 class="title">' . get_the_title()  . '</h5>';
$output .= '<h5 class="subtitle">'. get_the_subtitle() . '</h5>';
$output .= '<span class="categories">' . substr( trim( $category_names ), 0, -2 ) . '</span>';
$output .= '</a>';
```

I can't seem to find where goes wrong. Here is a part of the CSS. Is this the correct place?

```
/* -------------------------------------------------- */
/*  Projects Carousel
/* -------------------------------------------------- */

.no-js .projects-carousel, .no-js .post-carousel {
  border-top: 1px solid #efefef;
  margin: 15px -20px 60px 0;
  padding: 25px 0 0;
}

.projects-carousel > li, .post-carousel > li, #portfolio-items > article {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 20px 0 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.projects-carousel > li, .post-carousel > li { width: 220px; }

.no-js .post-carousel > li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}

.no-js .projects-carousel > li, .no-js #portfolio-items > article { margin-bottom: 40px; }

.projects-carousel a, #portfolio-items article .project-meta {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #efefef;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.projects-carousel a { padding: 20px 0 0; }

#portfolio-items article a, #portfolio-items article .audio-player, #portfolio-items article .video-player { margin: 0 auto; }

.projects-carousel img, #portfolio-items article img {
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
  filter: alpha(opacity=70); /* Fallback for old IE */
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.no-js .projects-carousel img, .no-js #portfolio-items article img { margin-bottom: 0; }

.projects-carousel img { margin: -25px auto 20px; }

.projects-carousel .title, #portfolio-items > article .title, .projects-carousel .subtitle, #portfolio-items > article .subtitle {
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: -1px 0 0;
}

.projects-carousel > li .categories, #portfolio-items > article .categories, #portfolio-items > article a + .project-meta .categories{
  color: #aeaeae;
  display: block;
  font-style: italic;
  margin: -1px 0 20px;
}
#portfolio-items > article .categories { margin-bottom: 19px; }

.projects-carousel a:hover, #portfolio-items > article:hover {
  background: #f8f8f8;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f15a23;
}

.not-ie .projects-carousel a:hover:after, .not-ie #portfolio-items > article:hover:after {
  background: #f15a23;
  bottom: -2.5px;
  content: '';
  left: 50%;
  display: block;
  height: 5px;
  margin: 0 0 0 -2.5px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  position: absolute;
  width: 5px;
}

.projects-carousel a:hover img, #portfolio-items > article:hover img {
  filter: alpha(opacity=100); /* Fallback for old IE */
  opacity: 1;
}

.projects-carousel a:hover .title, #portfolio-items > article:hover .title, .projects-carousel a:hover .subtitle, #portfolio-items > article:hover .subtitle { color: #f15a23; }
```

Comment: pure html issue, nothing to do with php

Comment: Any idea how can I fix this?

Comment: this will be to do with your css

Comment: I cant seem to find where it went wrong. Is the css snippet above correct place to look at?

Comment: Checked the HTML source of your page, `.subtitle` _is_ showing up after `.title`, it's empty though.

Comment: @godfrzero yea the content of the subtitle went above text "PORTFOLIO". Any idea why is that so?

Comment: @Dagon I've included the html snippet. is that the place to look at?

Comment: @TobyAllen I've included the html snippet. is that the place to look at? Have tried editing them but still not right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm writing this based on the two assumptions (based on the code you've provided):

- You're using WordPress
- You're using the [WP Subtitle](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-subtitle/) plugin

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

The documentation for the `get_the_subtitle` function [here](https://github.com/benhuson/wp-subtitle/wiki/get_the_subtitle) accepts a 4th boolean parameter `$echo`. When true, this actually echoes the output into your template rather than returning it, which is why the text appears above the block I'm presuming is rendered by your function. By default, this is true.

Instead of:

```
$output .= '<h5 class="subtitle">'. get_the_subtitle() . '</h5>';
```

Try using [`the_subtitle`](https://github.com/benhuson/wp-subtitle/wiki/the_subtitle)

```
$output .= the_subtitle('<h5 class="subtitle">', '</h5>', false);
```

This will take care of wrapping the subtitle with the `h5` tag, and return the value, instead of echoing it, which will then be concatenated with `$output`.

#### Details for the curious

So, why is `get_the_subtitle` not working as expected while `get_the_title` is? The functions that are natively provided by WP usually have two forms: `x` and `get_x`. The main difference being that `x` will echo the output and `get_x` will return the output. Generally, `x` is used to inject the output directly into the template while The Loop is running. `get_x` is used within PHP functions which need to operate on the returned value.

In this respect, the behavior of `get_the_subtitle` and `the_subtitle` seem rather non-standard for WP.